# Fetching every document from a single collection in a MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, vue.js

So I want to fetch every document in my MongoDB collection. I used method `find()` to get every property from a document.

```
    app.get ('/galerija', async (req , res) => {
    let db = await connect();
    let cursor = await db.collection('galerija').find();
    let results = await cursor.toArray();

    res.json(results);
});
```

What I need is to get all properties in one array (I don't want to use this: `data[1].email`), so how do I get every property of an email for example? When I try `data.email` it says that it is undefined. Please help. Here is that file from services:

```
async dohvati_objavu() {   
    
    let response = await Service.get(`/galerija`);
    
    let data = response.data;
    
    console.log("Current posts in services: "+data.email)  
    
        return data.map( function(data) {return{
            id: data._id,
            email: data.email,
            naslov: data.naslov,
            noviOpisSlike: data.noviOpisSlike,
            slika: data.slikaReference,
        };   
});
},
```

This is when I test with console.log:
[image]

In a Vue file I also want to read property of every document in mongo for every single property of `objava`it also shows me `[Object object]`:

```
async dohvatiObjavu(){
         this.objava = await Objave.dohvati_objavu();
        console.log("Current posts: " + this.objava);   
}
```

Comment: Well, at the time of your `console.log`, `data` is an array and there is no `email` property on an array. Did you mean to put the `console.log()` inside the `map` to log out `email` of each item? Also be careful calling the array `data` as well as each item `data` [no-shadow](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow). For testing, you could change your console.log to something like `console.log("Current posts in services: "+data[0].email)`

Comment: Okay, but in data I get `Object` `object`, so how to directly get access with `email`? And how to pass that value in the other Vue file? I used this syntax to get the access of first `email` in data, but I want to get access of a value of every property in document that is stored in mongo? Please write this in answer I would be very grateful.

Comment: Need more information to provide an answer. Do you get `[Object object]` when you try to render an item in the vue template? Share what is printed if you do `console.log(data)` in `dohvati_objavu()`.

Comment: Okay, I updated my question with a screenshot, i get `[Object object]` that's right! Please help

Comment: Try using JSON.stringify to wrap the object when it is logging.

Comment: When I wrapped it, it shows me the information I wanted, but how do I do `JSON.stringify` for properties which I called with objects? For example on the other Vue I have `this.objava`, it also shows `[Object object]`

Comment: I also updated the function `dohvatiObjavu()` in my question which is in my Vue file, please help!